# Convert speciifc format of string to DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I have 2 strings like this -
"Aug 14, 2019 09:56:33.359571620" and 
"Aug 14, 2019 09:56:33.359584300" .
I want to convert it into DateTime format in C# so that I can get the difference between two timestamps in Nanoseconds. How to do this?

I tried something like this -

```
DateTime  MyDateTime = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32("2019"), GetMonthNumber("Aug"), Convert.ToInt32("14"), Convert.ToInt32("09"), Convert.ToInt32("56"), Convert.ToInt32("33"));
MyDateTime.AddTicks(359571620);
DateTime MyDateTime2 = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32("2019"), GetMonthNumber("Aug"), Convert.ToInt32("14"), Convert.ToInt32("09"), Convert.ToInt32("56"), Convert.ToInt32("33"));
MyDateTime2.AddTicks(359584300);
TimeSpan ts = MyDateTime2 - MyDateTime;
Console.WriteLine(ts.Ticks);
```

The above code returns 0 but I am expecting 12680 as the output.

Comment: DateTime.ParseExact() is what you need.

Comment: _**I want to convert this into DateTime format**_ Sorry but that's quite wrong. A `DateTime` instance does not have any internal format. It is a numeric value which is based on `Ticks`. "Format" concept _only_ applies when you get it's _textual_ (aka `string`) representation.

Comment: Try using [custom date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) for parsing.

Comment: As an addition, a `DateTime` does _not_ contains timezone information. That's why there is no way to parse it your `Eastern Daylight Time` part [without escaping it as a string literal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#Literals).

Comment: **First,** I don't downvote because it is a direct question, **how to convert a string with a custom date format to DateTime?** Now the correct thing is you modify the question, because as @SonerGönül mentioned DateTime doesn't have a format

Comment: @SonerGönül  I have rephrased my question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should assign it back after adding ticks

```
DateTime  MyDateTime = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32("2019"), GetMonthNumber("Aug"), Convert.ToInt32("14"), Convert.ToInt32("09"), Convert.ToInt32("56"), Convert.ToInt32("33"));
MyDateTime = MyDateTime.AddTicks(359571620);
DateTime MyDateTime2 = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32("2019"), GetMonthNumber("Aug"), Convert.ToInt32("14"), Convert.ToInt32("09"), Convert.ToInt32("56"), Convert.ToInt32("33"));
MyDateTime2 = MyDateTime2.AddTicks(359584300);
TimeSpan ts = MyDateTime2 - MyDateTime;
Console.WriteLine(ts.Ticks);
```

> DateTime.AddTicks does **not** modify that date value, instead it returns a new one

Comment: Explanation: DateTime.AddTicks does *not* modify that date value, instead it returns a *new* one.

Comment: @HansKeﬆing, thanks. make sense to add reason. i have copied your explanation to my post

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
string dateformat = "Aug 14, 2019 09:56:33.359571620 Eastern Daylight Time";
DateTime anser = DateTime.ParseExact(dateformat.Substring(0,dateformat.IndexOf(".")), "MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Based on TimeZone

```
TimeZoneInfo tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
string dateformat = "Aug 14, 2019 09:56:33.359571620 Eastern Daylight Time";
DateTime anser = DateTime.ParseExact(dateformat.Substring(0,dateformat.IndexOf(".")), "MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime dateeee=TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(anser, tzi);
```

Comment: I don't think this is the right way to do it. Also you ignore the milliseconds part in your code which creates a different `DateTime` instance.

Comment: @atk Actually, Please check my rephrased question. Timezone can be ignored. But nanoseconds need to be included

Comment: For the sub-second part, there is an ["fffff" format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#fffffffSpecifier)